# How to auto reload next.js running with static site generation?

Tags: javascript, static, next.js

`next dev` allows you view websites while developing when you're using server-side generation.

When you're using static site generation, you first have to `next build`, and then do `next start` every time you want to refresh your changes.

Is there a `next dev` alternative for static sites? Something I can use while development.

Answer (score 3):

Next.js will pre-render the pages that don't have blocking data requirements - *Static Generation*.

You decide per-page if it will be statically rendered at build time or if will be server-rendered on-demand.

The way that Pre-rendering works in Next.js is that the page is rendered to HTML either at build-time or on-demand, this generated HTML will be optimized automatically.

> When you're using static site generation, you first have to next build, and then do next start every time you want to refresh your changes.

This is wrong.

`next build` simply builds the application for production usage and `next start` starts a Next.js production server

Just run `next` if you are in development mode and `next build` + `next start` if you are in production.